# Sort object in ArrayList using Quick Sort without Comparable

Tags: java

I am trying to sort an object within an `ArrayList` in descending order using Quick Sort. I don't want to use the `Comparable` interface that java provides for classes. In the object, there is an average method, in the `Team` class, that I'd like to use to sort the objects by.

Below I have a Bubble Sort algorithm that I implemented within the main method, and it ended up working fine. The reason that I've gotten this to work rather than the Quick Sort is that it requires methods like `partition` and `sort`, for example. The primary issue that I am having is accessing the methods that I need from the `Team` class into the `BubbleSort` class. I have tried `BubbleSort extends Team`, but then the issue that I run into is it requires me to feed arguments to the `BubbleSort` class that originated from the `Team` class. **Is there a way around me supplying those arguments in?** **What other approaches can I take?**

```
for (int i = 0; i < team.size() - 1; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < team.size() - i - 1; j++) {
    if (team.get(j).getAverage() < team.get(j + 1).getAverage()) {
      Team temp = team.get(j);
      team.set(j, team.get(j + 1));
      team.set(j + 1, temp);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a [repl.it](https://repl.it/@LoweMan/What-I-have-so-far) of the program thus far.

Comment: I don't get what the concrete problem is. What is the method of the Team class that you need to acess other than getAverage()? And why can't you access it?

Comment: @JBNizet I can access it I just then have to insert the arguments from the Team class as well which is something I don't want to do.

Comment: That doesn't mean anything to me. Post the code that you wrote, and tell precisely what the problem is in that code.

Comment: @JBNizet I made edits to the repl.it. Run the program and open `Main.java` and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: No, I don't, sorry. QuickSort has no reason to extend Team. If you really want to put your sorting method in that class rather than directy in Main, then it should be defined as `public static void sort(List<Team> teams)`. And of course, to call that method, you need to pass it the list  of teams that you want it to sort. If this sort() method needs to partition the list, then add a private static method named partition() in QuickSort.

Comment: @JBNizet This `List<Team> teams` was the key thing that I was missing in all of my other attempts. Sorry for the confusing question but I got it working :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Comparator` for custom sorting which is what you want by comparing `getAverage()` methods

Check out this `QuickSort` implementation: https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.13/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/QuickSort.html

It takes `list` and `Comparator` as parameters for sorting. You could just use that.

```
QuickSort.sort(team, (t1, t2) -> Double.compare(t1.getAverage(), t2.getAverage());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the logic you are looking for, go through the code , have commented what you need to modify!! note that it sorts item in ascending order!!

```
public class QuickSort
{       
    int[] nums = null; //this should be the arrayList of Team class in your case, say ArrayList<Team>() teams = null;

    /*this piece of code can be any where in your project, just placed it here in main function so that you could easily compile and run it*/
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int[] nums = {1,5,9,2,7,8,4,2,5,8,9,12,35,21,34,22,1,45}; 
        QuickSort qs = new QuickSort(nums);
        qs.quickSort(0,nums.length-1);
        qs.print();
    }

    QuickSort(int[] nums)//this should be the arrayList of Team class in your case, say ArrayList<Team>() teams
    {
        this.nums = nums;
    }

    /**
     * left and right are indices in array whereas
     * pivot is one of the values stored in array; in your case,it should be averageValue of Team stored in the arrayList
     * also, nums[leftIndex],nums[rightIndex],nums[right] should be replaced by 
     * teams.get(leftIndex).getAverage(),teams.get(rightIndex).getAverage(),teams.get(right).getAverage!!
     */
    int partition(int left, int right , int pivot)
    {
        int leftIndex = left -1;
        int rightIndex = right;
        int temp = 0;
        while(true)
        {
            while( nums[++leftIndex] < pivot );
            while( rightIndex>0 && nums[--rightIndex] > pivot );

            if( leftIndex >= rightIndex ) break;
            else//swap value at leftIndex and rightIndex
            {
                temp = nums[leftIndex];
                nums[leftIndex]= nums[rightIndex];
                nums[rightIndex] = temp;
            }
        }

        //swap value at leftIndex and initial right index
        temp = nums[leftIndex];
        nums[leftIndex]= nums[right];
        nums[right] = temp;

        return leftIndex;
    }

    void quickSort( int leftIndex , int rightIndex)
    {
        if( rightIndex-leftIndex <= 0 ) return;
        else
        {
            int pivot = nums[rightIndex];
            int partitionIndex = partition(leftIndex, rightIndex , pivot);
            quickSort(leftIndex,partitionIndex-1);
            quickSort(partitionIndex+1,rightIndex);
        }
    }

    void print()
    {
        for( int i = 0 ; i < nums.length ; i++ )
        {
            System.out.print(nums[i]+", ");
        }
    }

}
```